# Django No Reverse Match, Context is breaking my code

Tags: python, django, django-views

I've narrowed it down to when i add context to my return render(request) line is when my code breaks, but i can't figure out why. I'm not sure what errors to give or what parts of my code you need, but here you go.

```
NoReverseMatch at /gallery/gallery
Reverse for 'photo' with arguments '(2,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['gallery/photo']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/gallery/gallery
Django Version: 3.2.3
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'photo' with arguments '(2,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['gallery/photo']
Exception Location: C:\Users\ScrillaGorilla\PycharmProjects\Mustache Website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  C:\Users\ScrillaGorilla\PycharmProjects\Mustache Website\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.6
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\ScrillaGorilla\\PycharmProjects\\Mustache Website\\mustache',
 'C:\\Users\\ScrillaGorilla\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\ScrillaGorilla\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\ScrillaGorilla\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\ScrillaGorilla\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38',
 'C:\\Users\\ScrillaGorilla\\PycharmProjects\\Mustache Website\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\ScrillaGorilla\\PycharmProjects\\Mustache '
 'Website\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 16 Sep 2021 06:49:31 +0000
```

and this is my code. if that helps. this is my views.py file.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Category, Photo
from django.db import models


# Create your views here.
def photogallery(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    photos = Photo.objects.all()
    context = {'categories': categories, 'photos': photos}
    return render(request, 'picturegallery/pictures.html', context)

def viewPhoto(request, pk):
    photo = Photo.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request,'picturegallery/photo.html', {'photo': photo})

def addPhoto(request):
    return render(request,'picturegallery/ADD.html')
```

and this is my models.py file.

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Photo(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

this is the URL.py file

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url('gallery', views.photogallery, name="gallery"),
    url('photo', views.viewPhoto, name="photo"),
    url('add/', views.addPhoto, name="add"),
]
```

Comment: The lookup is defined in your `urls.py`. Could you show that too?

Comment: Will do, I just added it.

Comment: `url('photo', views.viewPhoto, name="photo")` doesn't catch a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was in my URL.py file. I changed the code to this and it worked.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('gallery', views.photogallery, name="gallery"),
    path('photo/<str:pk>/', views.viewPhoto, name="photo"),
    path('add/', views.addPhoto, name="add"),
]
```